# I want to pass different input arguments to a single jar through shell script

Tags: linux, shell, twitter, cron

I am running a jar every 30 mins through a `cron` job:

```
java -cp jarname args[0]
```

These args are `twitter4j.properties`.

I feel My question is not clear..
1. I will get  a word.list file with n nummber of lines
2. I am iterating through lines when line is 400 that 400 lines I am passing to jar file as args[1] and consider in this case my args[0] is t1-properties
3. For suppose if my word.list contains 600 lines then for first 400 lines the jar has to be executed then for Second 200 line another jar has to be executed with t2-properties
4.so ultimately for every 400 lines jar has to be executed with different properties file

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking to do something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
     java -cp jarname.jar twitter4j.properties
     sleep 30m
     #somehow get update for the twitter4j.properties
done
```

This will just run infintely in a terminal until you press `ctrl+c` Save the above file as: `myscript.sh` then type: `chmod u+x myscript.sh` so it has permission to execute and to run type: `. ./myscript.sh`